# Como fazer o site executar um saquencia de codigos com determinado usuario?

Tags: php, if

Bom dia, tenho uma pagina de acesso administrativo para os ADMs do meu site mas tem uma parte do código em uma das paginas, para criar e modificar usuários e senhas, que eu gostaria que aparecesse somente quando o usuário "TESTES" estiver conectado na pagina.Sou um pouco leigo em PHP então acredito que tenha feito alguma coisa errada ou esteja faltando alguma coisa.

Dentro dessa pagina tem uma STRING que chama o nome do usuário conectado, e estou usando essa mesma STRING para fazer, que seria `$_SESSION['nome_usuario']`.

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['nome_usuario'] = "TESTES") { ?>
   "Codigos em HTML e PHP que cria e modifica usuarios"...
<?php } ?>
```

No caso queria que `SE` usuário for igual a "TESTES" ele exiba os códigos e se não for igual não apresente nada. Desde ja agradeço a toda ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente, quando desenvolvemos um sistema de login, registramos o `id` do usuário que está conectado, que seria o correto você fazer.

Neste caso, como você faz a comparação de usuário, sendo usuário teste, podes resolver este impasse da seguinte forma:

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['nome_usuario'] == "TESTES") { ?>
   echo "Codigos em HTML e PHP que cria e modifica usuarios";
<?php } ?>
```

Usa-se o `==` para verificar igualdade, se você usar apenas `=`, você não conseguirá comparar, e sim estará setando/atribuindo a session como usuário teste.

A outra forma que você pode fazer, que seria a forma correta:

No momento em que você faz a verificação de login e senha no banco de dados, você define também:

```
$_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $row['id_usuario'] // usuário do banco de dados
```

E na sua verificação de usuários, você pode verificar da seguinte forma:

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['nome_usuario'] == 1) { ?>
   echo "Codigos em HTML e PHP que cria e modifica usuarios";
<?php } ?>
```

Neste caso, `id=1`, é o id de testes.

Comment: broder, coloquei o echo mas não to conseguindo aplicar o codigo, dentro do HTML e PHP tem aspas simples e dupla, qualquer uma das duas que eu colocar para o echo vai ser quebrado no meio do codigo.

Comment: Quando tiver aspas, você pode fazer: echo "meu conteudo de testes \"xxxx\" ";

Comment: peguei o codigo e criei em outro arquivo uma `STRING` para chamar ele, mas na pagina esta aparecendo um erro e não mostra o codigo. ele ta dando esse erro

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\fraturaexposta.esy.es\Login\Paginas\functions\criausuario.php on line 10`

``

Comment: e o erro seria no if dessa parte do codigo `// Apaga usuários

if ( isset( $_GET['del'] ) ) {

 // Delete de cara (sem confirmação)

 $pdo_insere = $conexao_pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE user_id=?');

 $pdo_insere->execute( array( (int)$_GET['del'] ) );

 

 // Redireciona para o index.php

 header('location: ../index.php');

}`

Comment: usei exatamente como vc mostrou no primeiro exemplo e usei \ antes das aspas duplas

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer esta verificação com este código, alterando somente o operação de atribuição **`=`**, para um operador de comparação **`==`**

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['nome_usuario'] == "TESTES") { ?>
   "Codigos em HTML e PHP que cria e modifica usuarios"...
<?php } ?>
```

É recomendável que você faça esta verificação:

- Ao acessar esta página que cria e modifica usuários, caso não seja o usuário de testes mostre uma mensagem de erro;
- Caso exista um menu que vá para esta página, deve ser oculto também o link que direcione para esta página.